# How does the Benedicts Test work?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, structural-biology

What exactly is the mechanism by which Benedict’s test works for reducing sugars? As I understand it the free hemiacetal groups on reducing sugars opens up and an aldehyde is formed, this is then oxidised by Cu<sup>2+</sup> which then results in a red copper(I) oxide.

RCHO + 2 Cu<sup>2+</sup>+ 5 OH<sup>-</sup> → RCOO<sup>-</sup> + Cu<sub>2</sub>O + 3 H<sub>2</sub>O.

The equation above isn’t really clear to me, what is exactly going on?

Additionally why are alkaline conditions required for the test? And if a red precipitate is formed how come there is such a wealth of colours observed (green, yellow, orange) for varying concentrations of reducing sugars?

Perhaps these are a couple of questions too many :D

Comment: In addition to the post linked above you can look at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62352/why-is-the-reduction-by-sugars-more-efficient-in-basic-solutions-than-in-acidic

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40127/why-does-fructose-reduce-tollens-reagent-and-fehlings-solution

Comment: And: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82677/why-are-different-colors-according-to-sugar-concentration-observed-in-benedict